# Selenium, locate cell in table

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cell

I am new to selenium and was hoping someone can help me with this. I'm trying to locate a specific cell in a table and return its text contents. The table is represented by the `html` below:

```
<h2>Test #2</h2>
<table border="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1:1</td>
         <td>1:2</td>
         <td>1:3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2:1</td>
         <td>2:2</td>
         <td>2:3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>3:1</td>
         <td>3:2</td>
         <td>3:3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I am trying to return the text from the cell with **3:2**. What do I need to change for that to happen?

This is what I have so far:

```
public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
    getValue(1, 3);
}

public void getValue(int row, int col) {
    List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#req2 table tbody tr"));
    List<WebElement> tableCol = tableRows.get(row - 1).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    System.err.println(tableCol.get(col - 1).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `CssSeleector`

```
tbody>tr:nth-child(3)>td:nth-child(2)
```

`nth-child()` function gives you the flexibility to easily find the child with different `index`

I strongly suggest you use this with some kind of `explicit` wait to properly locate the element

```
By css = By.cssSelector("tbody>tr:nth-child(3)>td:nth-child(2)");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css));
System.out.println(myDynamicElement.getText());
```

Print

> 3:2

With a slight change in your code it looks like the following

```
@Test
public void DemoTest() throws InterruptedException {

   System.out.println(test2());


}

public String test2() throws InterruptedException {
    return getValue(3, 2).getText() ;
}

public WebElement getValue(int row, int col) {

    By css = By.cssSelector("tbody>tr:nth-child(" + row + ")>td:nth-child(" + col + ")");
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(css));

    return myDynamicElement;
}
```

print

> 3:2